# Asterisk cmd Transfer() after Answer()

Tags: asterisk

I need to transfer a call using the asterisk 'transfer' function after the 'answer' function answers the call.

If I transfer the call without answering with the 'answer' works normally. If I transfer after the answer the error at the end of the post is displayed in the cli:

My context is simple... the connection should be answered and the user will enter DTMF and the connection will be transferred with the transfer.

It needs to be with the transfer because it is a sip redirect server.

Works:

```
exten => s,1,Transfer(SIP/1120@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

Not Works:

```
exten => s,1,Answer()
...
read some dtmf
...
exten => s,n,Transfer(SIP/1120@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
```

The error is:

```
[2018-01-22 07:31:56] NOTICE[32021]: chan_sip.c:20716 handle_response_refer: SIP transfer to <sip:1120@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx> failed, REFER not allowed.
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1313001-000e0e7c' status is 'UNKNOWN'
```

Answer (score 1):

Transfer function "before answer" use SIP 301 redirect.

There is NO WAY use 301 Redirect after 200 ok(answer). Standart not support that.

Instead used REFER.

http://www.tech-invite.com/fo-sip/tinv-fo-sip-service-05.html

Your message say, that other side say it not support REFER.